# NSExpression customization

Tags: swift, nsexpression

```
extension String {
    var expression: NSExpression {
        return NSExpression(format: self)
    }
}

infix operator ^^
func ^^ (radix: Int, power: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(pow(Double(radix), Double(power)))
}
```

How can I add my infix operator in the `NSExpression`?
I want to add `^^` as the power calculation operator in the `NSExpression`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for extending the syntax understood by `NSExpression`.

Try using [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) instead. It already uses `**` as the exponentiation operator.